# For loop adds 20 minutes till the time is 17:16

Tags: python

I want my code to print:
The train will leave at 13:36 tomorrow
.
.
The train will leave at 17:16 tomorrow
Asuming that trains leave every 20 minutes.

Here is what i have tryed so far

```py
h = 13
m = 36
i = 20
while(True):
    m = m + i
    if m >= 60:
        h = h + 1 and m = 0
        if h > 17 and m > 16:
            break
        print("The train will leave at {0:0d}:{1:0d} tomorrow".format(h, m))
```

When running the code i get "SyntaxError: can't assign to operator"
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `h=h+1 and m=0` is not a correct syntax. What do you want to do?

Comment: If you just want to do those two assignments just remove the `and` and put the assignments in two lines.

Comment: Thx that solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue causing this error is `h=h+1 and m=0`, if you want to do this in one line you could do `h, m = h + 1, m` although personally I would split it over 2 lines.

Apart from that there are some other issues:

1. Indentation on `if h>17 and m>16:` is wrong. It will only check this statement when 
   `m` was first `>= 60` because of this `m` is being reset to `0` and `m` will never be `>16` so the while loop would run forever.

   Solve this by:

   ```
   if m>=60:
       h=h+1
       m=0
   if h>17 and m>16:
       break
   ```
2. Because you reset `m=0` it will never be `16` again in the future. `16 -> 36 -> 56 -> 76 -> 0 -> 20 -> 40 -> 60 -> 0 -> ...` you can solve this by resetting `m=m-60` when it exceeds `60`

The final script would look something like:

```
h = 13
m = 36
i = 20
while(True):
    m=m+i
    if m>=60:
        h=h+1
        m=m-60
    if h>17 and m>16:
        break
    print("The train will leave at {0:0d}:{1:0d} tomorrow".format(h, m))
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't even attempt to work with time in such a naive way. There are so many use and edge cases to think about and handle.

Use proper time objects (in this case `datetime` because pure [`time` objects do no support `timedelta` calculations](https://bugs.python.org/issue1487389#msg54803)).

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

current_time = datetime.now().replace(hour=13, minute=16)
end_time = datetime.now().replace(hour=17, minute=16)
delta_minutes = 20

while current_time <= end_time:
    print("The train will leave at {} tomorrow".format(current_time.strftime('%H:%M')))
    current_time += timedelta(minutes=delta_minutes)
```

Outputs

```
The train will leave at 13:16 tomorrow
The train will leave at 13:36 tomorrow
The train will leave at 13:56 tomorrow
The train will leave at 14:16 tomorrow
The train will leave at 14:36 tomorrow
The train will leave at 14:56 tomorrow
The train will leave at 15:16 tomorrow
The train will leave at 15:36 tomorrow
The train will leave at 15:56 tomorrow
The train will leave at 16:16 tomorrow
The train will leave at 16:36 tomorrow
The train will leave at 16:56 tomorrow
The train will leave at 17:16 tomorrow
```